# Jackson fails to deserialize to class with private constructor after migration to Java 17 + jakarta libraries

Tags: jackson, java-17, jakarta-migration, private-constructor

The REST server uses Jackson deserialisation to a class (a.b.c.d.Application) which has a private constructor which worked just fine when using Java 8. After we migrated to Java 17 and replacing all javax.* to jakarta.* libraries, I am seeing this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.eclipse.yasson.internal.ReflectionUtils cannot access a member of class a.b.c.d.Application with modifiers "private"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:489)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.ReflectionUtils.createNoArgConstructorInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:274)
Wrapped by: jakarta.json.bind.JsonbException: Can't create instance
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.ReflectionUtils.createNoArgConstructorInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:276)
```

I tried adding @JsonCreator annotation to the private constructor which could help Jackson use the constructor but with no luck.

Comment: Are you making use of [`org.eclipse:yasson`](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.eclipse/yasson)? If so, which version of the library is in use?

Comment: No, I don't use the library directly. It could be that jakarta.json uses org.eclipse:yasson

Comment: Update on this -- As per the jakarta specs, we cannot have private constructor. https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonb/3.0/jakarta-jsonb-spec-3.0 , hence there is no way to deserialise to a class with private constructor